# How do I transfer data between two computers ?

Tags: python, rpc

I have two computers on a network. I'll call the computer I'm working on `computer A` and the remote `computer B`. My goal is to send a command to B, gather some information, transfer this information to computer A and use this in some meaningfull way. My current method follows:

1. Establish a connection to B with *paramiko*.
2. Use paramiko to execute a remote command e.g. `paramiko.exec_command('python file.py')`.
3. Write the information to a file with *pickle*, and use `paramiko.ftp` to transfer the file to  computer A.
4. Open this file and parse the information back into a usable form, like a class or dictionary.

This seems very ad-hoc. My question is, is there a better way to transfer data between computers using Python? I know how to transfer files, this is a different question. I want to make an object on B and use it on A.

Comment: You might want to check out [Pyro](http://irmen.home.xs4all.nl/pyro/).

Comment: Have you tried [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). It's the best python framework I've encountered for custom client/server applications like the one you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing something similar on a larger scale (with 15 clients). I use the pexpect module to do essentially ssh commands on the remote machine (computer B). Another module to look into would be the subprocess module.

Answer (score 0):

We are developing [Versile Python](https://versile.com/products/vpy/) which provides such object-level interaction, you may want to have a look. It includes an object-level framework for [streams](https://versile.com/doc/vpy/current/library/vse/stream.html) which could be applied to your use case (transferring file data).